# What event could be used to know whenever a screen (child of a state) is showed - flex

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3

I know the event "show" works for View stack i.e. I can use this event (capture it and do some processing) to know whenever my view stack child gets displayed in screen.  But when I am trying to use the same event for a child of a state it doesn't work (i.e. breakpoint set at its event handler never gets hit). Similary, creationComplete only works when the screen is visited for the first time.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I am really confused by the question. Could you elaborate/clarify/simplify ?

Comment: I need an event something like onPageLoad in aspx. So that everytime that screen shows up - I can do some processing.  Please note that "show" event doesn't work if the screen is a state child.  For view stack child, it does work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to add a listener on the enterState event?

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/states/State.html?filter_coldfusion=9&filter_flex=3&filter_flashplayer=10&filter_air=1.5#event:enterState